# Is copy elision valid in default function arguments?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this code:

```
struct foo;
foo *p;   

struct foo {
    foo() { p = this; }
};

bool default_arg ( foo f = foo() )
{
    return p == &f;
}

bool passed_in ( foo& f )
{
    return p == &f;
}   

int main()
{
    std::cout << default_arg() << '\n';

    foo f = foo();
    std::cout << passed_in(f) << '\n';
}
```

I would expect that for the calls to both `default_arg` and `passed_in`, `f` will just be default-constructed as the copy will be elided*. This would cause both calls to return `true`. However, neither [Clang 3.7 nor GCC 5.3](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7cac88e5230f77f) elide the copy in the default argument of `default_arg`.

Is copy elision valid in default arguments? Maybe I'm missing something obvious with how default arguments must be evaluated on every call.

---

**Edit:** The important part appears to be the presence of a user-declared copy-constructor. If this is present, copy elision occurs. Why should this make a difference?

---

*Obviously copy elision is currently optional, but I would expect Clang and GCC to do it when possible.

Comment: FYI; VS2015 behaves as clang and gcc.

Comment: What matters is whether the class is trivially copyable. The platform ABI may require sufficiently small trivially copyable classes to be passed in registers. When you attempt to take the address of such an object, it will have to be copied onto the stack so that it has an address for you to take.

Comment: btw... apart from the fact it is an interesting problem; isn't it a bad idea to rely on this, since it is not a rule but an optimization?

Comment: @user1810087 Absolutely, this is from a compiler test which my colleague found and was using to test his own compiler. He was wondering about the difference in behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) pointed out, copy-elision may not be possible when passing small trivially-copyable types to functions.

This is because the calling conventions for some ABIs (e.g. the System V ABI) assume that sufficiently small trivially-copyable types will be passed in registers rather than through memory. SysV, for example, will categorise such types in the `INTEGER` argument class, rather than the `MEMORY` class.

This means that if you pass such an argument to a function which requires taking the address of the parameter, the register contents will need to be copied onto the stack so that there is a valid address. As such, the copy from the rvalue argument to the by-value parameter cannot be carried out, even though the language rules may say its possible.

Of course, copy-elision in such a case is pretty useless for sake of efficiency, but for those curious, a simple way to make copy-elision occur on such platforms is to make the class not trivially-copyable. An example of this is to make the destructor user-provided:

```
struct foo {
    foo() { p = this; }
    ~foo(){} //user-provided
};
```

This causes copy-elision to occur on both Clang 3.7 and GCC 5.3.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1785b50785c874d2)

Comment: I'm not sure there's a point in forcing non-trivial-copyability here. We are talking about types small enough to be passed in registers, and simple enough that copying just copies the bytes. Any copy here is very cheap.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, the final bit is more for curiosity related to my original example, where copy elision changes the output of the program. I'll clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i didn't find the statement in the draft (yet) but on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> Even when copy elision takes place and the copy-/move-constructor is not called, it must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed.

I think the problem here is, the default copy/move constructors are optimized away so the compiler cannot elide the copy. But if you implement one of them elision takes place:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo;
foo *p;   

struct foo {
    foo() { p = this; std::cout << "default ctor\n"; }

    // define your own copy/move ctor
    // which are doing nothing
    foo(foo const& f) { std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; }
    foo(foo&& f) { std::cout << "move ctor\n"; }

};

bool default_arg ( foo f = foo() )
{
    return p == &f;
}

bool passed_in ( foo& f )
{
    return p == &f;
}   

int main()
{
    std::cout << default_arg() << '\n';

    foo f = foo();
    std::cout << passed_in(f) << '\n';
}
```

see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b7efc53f376f30a).

Comment: I don't think that cppreference quote applies here, it's talking about the restriction on copy elision for non-copyable, non-moveable types. The user-declared copy-constructor appears to be the important part, but I'm not sure why that makes a difference from the implicitly-declared one.

Comment: @TartanLlama still cannot find any gues in the draft, but omitting the implicit declared copy ctor seems to help even if you don't define copy or move ctors but a destructor ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94bb0efe90761fdb)). i'm still not sure why, but ...

Answer (score 0):

The rules for C++11 can be found in chapter 12.8(31) of the standard. Copy elision is allowed in 4 cases. The rule that should apply here is:

> when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference
>   would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified
>   type

But I have found this sentence in a Note (1.9(11)):

> subexpressions involved in evaluating default arguments are considered
>   to be created in the expression that calls the function, not the
>   expression that defines the default argument

So when `foo()` is default-constructed in `main` the whole thing should be similar to

```
bool passed_in_by_value ( foo f )
{
    return p == &f;
}

std::cout << passed_in_by_value(foo()) << '\n';
```

which also returns false. Maybe the compiler does not consider the value as temporary when assigning it to the argument anymore.

Not really an answer but maybe a hint...